# Remap Control+Command+F from Facebook to Full Screen

Tags: macos, keyboard, facebook

Many of my OS X applications have the `"Enter Full Screen"` action mapped to <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. When I hit this key-combo though I get a dialog that tells me that no Facebook account is configured, and the app does not enter full screen mode.

I've gone into System Preferences and looked for anything else mapped to <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and nothing was.

I also went into **System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Keyboard Shortcuts** → **Application Shortcuts**  and mapped <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to `"Enter Full Screen"` for all applications. Nothing changes.

Does anyone know how I can disable this annoying dialog?

Comment: Do you have a Facebook account configured under the Mail settings? So this happens in Safari and the Finder, for example?

Comment: Ok now control-command-f works for fullscreen in all apps for me. Maybe the keyboard shortcut I set in System Preferences took a while to take effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem too.  Turns out the **PandaBar** app was to blame.  It had overridden the Control-Command-F keyboard shortcut for posting to Facebook what I was listening to.

Go into PandaBar **Preferences -> Shortcuts** and change or clear the "Post to Facebook" shortcut.

Then the full screen shortcut will work as expected in all your other apps, without having to override it with System Preferences changes.